# Replace partial string values in pandas dataframes by using dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe like this

```
Date        Name
11-01-19    Craig-TX
22-10-23    Lucy-AR
```

I have dictionary

```
data ={'TX':'Texas','AR':'ARIZONA'}
```

I would like to replace partial string value from TX --> Texas and AR --> Arizona.

Resultant dataframe should be

```
Date        Name
11-01-19    Craig-Texas
22-10-23    Lucy-Arizona
```

Do we have any specific function to replace the values in each row?

Answer (score 1):

Adding `regex = True`

```
df=df.replace(data,regex=True)
       Date          Name
0  11-01-19   Craig-Texas
1  22-10-23  Lucy-ARIZONA
```

More safe, for example if the Name contain TX, using `replace` will fail

```
df.Name=df.Name.str.split('-',expand=True).replace({1:data}).agg('-'.join)
0       Craig-Lucy
1    Texas-ARIZONA
dtype: object
```

Comment: Can you please explain how the second option will work ?